# A word for an explosion of emotion

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

When I was reading *P.S Your Cat is Dead* by James Kirkwood, I remember stumbling upon a single word that meant an **explosion of positive emotion**, but I can't recall what that word was. The word had a heavily positive connotation. Any ideas?

Comment: All I can think of is something like an *impassioned outburst*.

Comment: If they are happy emotions, you could say you are **over the moon**.

Comment: How about *bubbles* of positive emotions **effervescent** :)

Comment: Quoting from the novel: "My expression must have said it all. The look on my face *fractured him*. He reared back, howling in laughter. This sudden explosion riled me ..." If this is the passage you mean, my response would be that "fracture" is being used figuratively to mean "amuse". At least one dictionary [lists this as slang](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fracture?s=t). I suppose the figurative meaning is descriptive of how laughter can suddenly "break out" of a person.

Answer (score 4):

Such an explosion of emotion can sometimes be referred to as an **outpouring** of emotion.  Merriam-Webster has:

> Outpouring(n): an act of expressing an emotion or feeling in a very powerful way

Comment: Does this word carry a positive charge? Or is it neutral? Or does it carry an undercurrent of negativity like effusion? I'm double checking because I'm looking for a word strictly with a positive connotation.

Comment: When you say "positive connotation", do you mean in the sense of the emotion itself, or judgement upon the person experiencing the emotion?  "Outpouring" doesn't generally imply any kind of judgement upon the outpourer.  Even when used with unpleasant emotions, like "outpouring of grief", it does not imply that the emotional display is inappropriate.  Other terms (like "outburst") can imply judgement.

Answer (score 3):

[Wellsprings of emotion can **gush**](https://books.google.com/books?id=PFX46CLqb0MC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=wellspring+of+emotions+gushed&source=bl&ots=09l6pWHvip&sig=Le7Zf884NygZw5CApStRQvulAtE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAWoVChMIi62o_5_-xgIVy1Y-Ch3GEQ6u#v=snippet&q=wellsprings%20of%20emotion%20gushed&f=false), [**erupt**](http://www.standard.net/Faith/2015/05/02/Spiritual-healer-uses-Celtic-Viking-traditions), or just about any word that would describe the action of a pent-up liquid escaping/flowing from its source. (Google books & Standard/net)

Comment: "outpouring" also fits the pattern of a emotion = pent-up liquid.

Comment: @Sawbones Wow, that's certainly better than my two and worthy of its own submission as an answer, imo.

Comment: Thanks -- I'd never noticed the pattern of emotion=pent-up liquid before, but it holds for almost every word I can think of

Answer (score 3):

**euphoria** (*noun*):

a feeling or state of intense excitement and happiness

> '*Even thinking about seeing it brings a feeling of euphoria so intense that I'm having to resist the urge to go and lie down.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/euphoria)

Further information is available at: [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphoria)

Comment: I can't accept this because it doesn't have the element of explosiveness I was asking for, but it does have a strong positive charge so it is half right.

Comment: Hi @KevinBehan there are several words that describe intense joy and pleasure, but other than 'euphoric', the only ones I can think of as possibly'explosive', are 'ecstasy/ecstatic' and 'orgasm/orgasmic'. I considered 'exuberance', but it really means 'full of fun' and 'boisterous/energetic', so it doesn't apply to extreme levels of emotion. Euphoria is usually, but not always, spontaneous.

Answer (score 2):

"**Effusion**" is defined by Merriam-Webster as "[an] unrestrained expression of words or feelings".

Comment: Effusive typically has a negative connotation.

Comment: If so, I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

*Your question covers **explosion** as something experienced, for which one of these words might be suitable*

Aflame, **galvanised**,

> galvanising   (adj)  [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/galvanising)
>   affected by emotion as if by electricity; thrilling

*...and dramatic displays of emotion, for which these would be more suitable*

**displayed
paroxysms** of mirth, rage, panic...

> paroxysm:  (noun) [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paroxysm)    A sudden attack or
>   outburst of a particular emotion or activity

*On the more positive, cheerful side (with nuance in brackets)*

> **ebullience** (jolly), **exhilaration**(full of joy), **exuberance**(bouncy).
>   based on [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exuberance)

Comment: I very much appreciate the thoroughness of your response and I apologize for revising my question. I just remembered that it was an explosion of positive emotion.

Comment: Paroxysms is very close, but I feel like the connotation is negative (am I wrong in thinking that?) Although ebullience, exuberance and exhilaration capture the right feeling, I chose the word explosion because I'm looking for more of a verb than an adjective.

Comment: @KevinBehan  I've heard paroxysms *of mirth* most often. But ="helpless with laughter.'  Fairly sure that James Kirkwood did *not* use that word. Upwelling is more likely. Or exuberance, if I had to bet.

Answer (score 1):

Catharsis?  The first word that came to mind, and I don't see it listed!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that an answer at StackExchange is expected to be *definitive* — yours should provide a complete explanation of *why* you suggest *catharsis*, including appropriate references and examples. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: I think _catharsis_ is a very reasonable suggestion—but as choster says, at this site we strongly prefer answers that don't require readers to go elsewhere to determine whether a suggested single-word answer makes sense. By providing a self-contained answer with reputable support (such as a dictionary definition), you will greatly strengthen your posted response.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the novel:

> My expression must have said it all. The look on my face ***fractured*** him. He reared back, howling in laughter. This sudden explosion riled me

In this passage, *fracture* is being used figuratively to mean *amuse*. [At least one dictionary lists this meaning, labeling it slang](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fracture?s=t). I suppose the figurative meaning is descriptive of laughter suddenly “breaking out” of a person.

Locating a forgotten word in a book can often be accomplished by going to [the book’s page in Google Book Search](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0312321201) and using the search box to search within the book. In this case the search word `explosion` quickly located the passage.

Answer (score 0):

> [**epiphany**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany) *noun*: **3a** (**1**) a usually sudden manifestation or perception of the essential nature or meaning of something (**2**) an intuitive grasp of reality through something (as an event) usually simple and striking (**3**) an illuminating discovery, realization, or disclosure. (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Comment: An epiphany is more of an intellectual explosion, so to speak, than an emotional one. But I do appreciate your response!

Comment: Thanks Kev, but an *epiphany* is not limited to a strictly cognitive experience. Though *epiphanies*often begin with an intellectual breakthrough, they often, even usually, lead to emotional ecstasy. *Epiphany* may not be the word you're looking for, but don't imagine the experience is merely intellectual.